# Problems calculating date

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me determine why this code is not working?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

const date = new Date();
const day = date.getUTCDate();
const month = date.getMonth(); //January is 0! 
const md = month + "." + day

if (md < 3.03) {
        var theDate = new Date();
    var award_year1 = date.getFullYear();
        var award_year2 = date.getFullYear() + 1;
}

else if (md > 3.03) {
        var theDate = new Date();
    var award_year1 = date.getFullYear() + 1;
        var award_year2 = date.getFullYear() + 2;
}

console.log(award_year1);
console.log(award_year2);
</script>
```

Today is June 7, so it should return award_year1 = 2019 and award_year2 = 2020.

Comment: `month + "" + day` will be `117` both for January the 17th and December the 7th just saying...

Comment: @JonasW Thanks..... you are correct!

Comment: @JonasW Thanks! again, you fixed the date calls for me. I changed it to month + "." + day and then put a period between the numbers. Brilliant!

Comment: if you are calculating the fiscal year why are using the date just compare your month to be lesser than or equals to 3.

Comment: @UllasHunka I am not calculating fiscal year, I need this calc to be flexible because the day and month changes from year to year

Comment: One question at a time, please.

Comment: Ok than compare (30 * {expected month}) to [{(current month -1) * 30} + current date].

Comment: Also, on the line `const md = month + "." + day`, `md` will be interpreted as a string. Do `parseFloat(month + "." + day)` to get a number.

Comment: @Barmar, sorry I did not know this was a policy. I will divide into two posts if you prefer. The first question has been solved. I figure they were two easy things to solve

Comment: @KatoFett Thank you. Good catch and sound advice.

Comment: @beingbecoming They might be easy, but if you get two answers, and one answers Q1 while the other answers Q2, how would you decide which one to accept?

Comment: @Barmar Sorry I'm new here. Fair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a suggestion to make your code a little more declarative/ easier to read. You can compare 2 date objects in the way you would expect to.

```js
const date = new Date();
let offset = 0;
const threshold = new Date();
threshold.setMonth(3);
threshold.setDate(3);
if (Date.now() > threshold) { //might be a bit easier to reason about
  offset = 1;
}
var theDate = new Date();
var award_year1 = date.getFullYear() + offset;
var award_year2 = date.getFullYear() + 1 + offset;

console.log(award_year1);
console.log(award_year2);
```